# Access an exterior object from php code inside a class located in a string executed with EVAL

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
class Context
{
  ...
  $public details;
  ...
}

$context = new Context();

class Info 
{
  ....
  $public $infoContext;

  public function show()
  {
    $infoContext = "<html><head></head><body><?php echo $context->details; ?></body><html>";
    eval( ' ?>'. $infoContext. '<?php ');
  }
}

$inf = new Info();

$info->show();
```

Unfortunately, this code not works, but this is what I want to achieve, I want to execute the php code **echo $context->details;** But I dont know how, please help...

Comment: Inject `$context` as a constructor argument for your `Info` class, so you can store it as a property (so it's no longer an "exterior" object); then use normal string interpolation to build `$infoContext` rather than that horrible string and eval

Comment: @MarkBaker please post an answer to be sure that I understand you correctly, I will test it then, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `$context` as a constructor argument for your `Info class`, so you can store it as a property (so it's no longer an "exterior" object); then use normal string interpolation to build `$infoContext` rather than that horrible string and eval

```
class Info 
{
    protected $context;
    ....
    public $infoContext;

    public function __construct($context) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function show()
    {
        $this->infoContext = "<html><head></head><body>" . $this->context->details . "</body><html>";
        echo $this->infoContext;
    }
}

$context = new Context();
$inf = new Info($context);


$info->show();
```

Comment: First, thanks for answer! It works, but in my case I must load a file content which has PHP code inside, and I don't know how to achieve this

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to build a full templating system. What's wrong with using an existing system like mustache or twig or blade?

Comment: I understand that this may be already done but I need it for my personal case of study and I need to go this way of implementation, may be you know some tricks to achieve this or it is too difficult ?

Comment: No, it isn't too difficult.... but it's too large a subject for a StackOverflow answer.... take a look at some of the template engines that I've listed, even Smarty, and see how they work

Comment: The above is giving me this: Trying to get property of non-object . Do you know why?

Comment: No I don't, but my guess would be that your $context object that my example passes to the constructor isn't actually an object, given that you were rather vague about it.... [here take a look at it working](https://3v4l.org/Imj2E)